# Can volts be counted and followed by a plural verb?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, tense-agreement

I am wondering which is correct: 100 voltages is/are applied.
And how about 'negative 22 voltages is/are applied'?

Answer (score 1):

"Voltage" is the force. "Volt" is the unit of measure of voltage.

> "What is the voltage?"
>   "The voltage is 100 volts."

So the correct noun is "volt", as you said in your title. And it's "100 volts is applied" and "-22 volts is applied".

Although the word is plural (you could say "1 volt is applied"), you're not applying each individual volt 100 times. You are applying one wire that is carrying 100 or -22 volts.

Comment: This is a decent answer, and I think it could be better if you explained how voltages can be used correctly in some contexts. For example, 'It is able to handle voltages from 10V to 42V.' I think it might be a little tricky for that voltage is countable in some situations.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally understand your answer. Then, does your answer apply to a unit of measure such as centimeters? Should I say "10 centimeters is...."? because it is whatever a length or a width of 10 cm?

Comment: Mostly, yes. "The stick is 10 centimeters long" or "10 centimeters is the length of ribbon that you'll need" both describe the (single) length of the stick and ribbon, not the 10 cms.